# Angular Generic Custom Validation Component

Tags: angular

I have some Angular that looks like the following for validating an input. I'm duplicating this code a lot (just swapping model/property).

I'd like to attempt to move it into a separate component I can just reference and pass it the variables.

What's the best way to do this? I'm not sure how to pass it in the Model itself and handle generic properties.

Code:

```
    <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="control-label" translate for="name">Name</label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="connector.name" #connectorName="ngModel" id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" required [class.is-invalid]="connectorName.invalid && (connectorName.dirty || connectorName.touched)">
                </div>

                <div *ngIf="connectorName.invalid && (connectorName.dirty || connectorName.touched)"
                     class="text-danger">
                    <div *ngIf="connectorName.errors.required" translate="Validation.RequiredField" [translateParams]="{Field: 'Name' | translate}">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Attempt at generic Component creation:

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'validation-display',
    templateUrl: './validation-display.component.html',
})
export class ValidationDisplayComponent {

    @Input()
    translateText: string;

    @Input()
    @ViewChild('element') input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, use what I call a "Custom Form Component".

This is a component that implements `ControlValueAccessor`.

It will works in templateDriven and reactiveForm forms.

You can find more informations here : https://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel